# How to solve attempt to read property "id" on null (Laravel-8)

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error while running
`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`
this command will create table in MySQL database and fill the database details DB_DATABASE in .env file.

````
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($model)
    {
    $user = Auth::user();
    model->created_by = $user->id ? $user->id : 1 ;
      });
      static::updating(function($model)
      {
       $user = Auth::user();```


Controller:
````

Comment: Use double question mark or shortcut of isset: `$user->id ?? 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the value of `$user` is `null` and `null` doesn't have any properties.

`$user` will always be `null` with your code as `Auth::user()` will be `null`. You have no authenticated `User` during the execution of your seeder.

If you want to assign a `User` to your `$model` and you have seeded your `User` table, you could get a `User` that way.

```
$model->created_by = \App\Models\User::where('id', 5)->first();
```

If you don't want a particular `User` then you could do:

```
$model->created_by = \App\Models\User::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
model->created_by = $user->id ? $user->id : 1 ;
```

to this:

```
model->created_by = $user ? $user->id : 1 ;
```

You must first check if the `$user` is empty or not.