# php 8: warning of attempt to read property "id" on null: wp tailor advanced

Tags: php, wordpress

I inherited an old wordpress website running on php 7.4 and with the website builder plugin "Tailor", which has been discontinued for some time now. This website serves as content source to be copied to the new, modernised website - that's why I want to keep the old outdated site. To have the new site running, i want to upgrade to php 8.1 but then the old site breaks (the template still shows correctly but the dynamic content is not displayed).
a php warning is shown:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "id" on null in /home/.sites/64/sitexxxxxx/web/wp-content/plugins/tailor-advanced/includes/helpers-general.php on line 258

looking in the code, i find this part around line 258:

```
$priority = 0;
    foreach ( (array) $element->controls() as $control ) { /* var $control Tailor_Control */
        if ( $control->section == 'colors' ) {
            $priority += 10;
        }
    }

    $element->add_setting( 'shadow_color', array(
        'sanitize_callback'     =>  'tailor_sanitize_color',
        'refresh'               =>  array(
            'method'                =>  'js',
        ),
    ) );
    $element->add_control( 'shadow_color', array(
        'label'                 =>  __( 'Shadow color', 'tailor-advanced' ),
        'type'                  =>  'colorpicker',
        'rgba'                  =>  '1',
        'dependencies'          =>  array(
            'shadow'                => array(
                'condition'             =>  'equals',
                'value'                 =>  '1',
            ),
        ),
        'priority'              =>  $priority += 10,
        'section'               =>  'colors',
    ) );

    //
    // Attribute settings
    //
    $shadow_control = false;
    foreach ( (array) $element->controls() as $control ) { /* var $control Tailor_Control */
        if ( $control->setting->id == 'shadow' ) {
            $shadow_control = $control;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $shadow_control ) {
        $priority = (int) $shadow_control->priority;

        $element->add_setting( 'shadow_horizontal', array(
            'sanitize_callback'     =>  'tailor_sanitize_number',
            'default'               =>  '0',
            'refresh'               =>  array(
                'method'                =>  'js',
            ),
        ) );
```

the line 258 is

```
if ( $control->setting->id == 'shadow' ) {
            $shadow_control = $control;
            break;
        }
```

is there a quick and dirty way to tweak the code so that the old site will work on php 8.1 until we have transferred the content we need to the new site?

Comment: `if ( $control->setting && $control->setting->id == 'shadow' ) `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve attempt to read property "id" on null (Laravel-8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002227/how-to-solve-attempt-to-read-property-id-on-null-laravel-8)

Comment: At a guess this version of WP is not ready for PHP8, so you may need to upgrade the WP version as well as the PHP version

Comment: thank you silver – this made the warning disappear!
still, the website breaks as described… @riggsfolly's guess that the wp-version or any of the active plugins is not ready for php 8 might be right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to access a property that doesn't exist.
I'd check to see if its set and then check for the value

```html
if(isset($control->setting)) {
    if($control->setting->id == 'shadow'){
      $shadow_control = $control;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm… i added your lines but this made the website present a white screen. i'm afraid the website has bigger issues than the lines of code i copied into my post. thanks anyway!